# SFTP stopped printing the message "Uploading <file> to /path/to/file"

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, sftp, informatica

```
echo cd $DEST >$DIR/$SFTP_CMD
echo put $FTP_FILE_NAME "$FTP_FILE_NAME(+1)" >> $DIR/$SFTP_CMD
echo quit >> $DIR/$SFTP_CMD

sftp -b $DIR/$SFTP_CMD $USER@$SERVER >> $LOG
```

Usually on successful SFTP, "Uploading file to path/file" is printed to stdout (log in this case). It stopped doing so. The FTP is still succeding but it is not printing "Uploading.* message to stdout". I don't know what would have changed that would cause this change. Has anyone face this before?

This script is triggered from Informatica - command task. The only thing that changed is that this workflow was migrated to informatica 10.

Comment: Can you please explain the downvote? This is a genuine question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the OpenSSH `sftp` utility doesn't print that message if it's run with the `-q` flag or the `-b` flag (which implies `-q`).

I have source code for some old versions of OpenSSH on hand. The change to suppress that message was made sometime between versions 6.0 and 6.6. It's possible that your Informatica update also involved an update to your OpenSSH software, and you're now running a newer version of the `sftp` utility.

The only solutions that come to mind are:

1. Get by without that message.
2. Avoid running `sftp` with `-b` or `-q`.
3. Revert to a sufficiently old copy of the `sftp` utility for this purpose.
4. Download the OpenSSH source code and build your own (possibly modified) version of the `sftp` utility.
5. Write your own sftp client using the language of your choice. Most modern programming languages have some kind of SSH/SFTP client library available.

Comment: That was indeed correct. Someone had updated OpenSSH to newer version.